# Duplicate Line Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I duplicate the line my cursor is on in Visual Studio 2022.

In VS 2017 and 2019, it was `Ctrl + D`.

But that command is not working in VS 2022.

Comment: You need to go to Tools =>Option =>Keyboard =>Choose (Default)  as the additinal mapping scheme.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ctrl+D should work

Maybe you have different keys assigned, or an extension is using it.

Have a look at your Keyboard settings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 13):

The chord <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then - <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> duplicates a line.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, the problem is VS 2022 tries to port previous mapping schemes and overwrites the default. Just go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard, mine had somehow defaulted to Visual C# 2005 so I set it back to (Default). I went from 2019 to 2022 so I am guessing this is a bug..[image]

Comment: Interesting. Because next time I tried to use it, it worked. May be a bug. ;)

Comment: Click the "Reset" button